# Java path required in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, makeprg, filetype-java

Normally you would compile java using this:

```
javac Hello.java
java Hello
```

Under certain conditions you can compile from Vim by just typing :make by placing this in .vimrc

```
autocmd Filetype java set makeprg=java\ %
```

Recently it hasn't been working though.

I've figured out that the path is the problem. How do I include it in my vimrc? I'm not sure exactly what the semantics behind that would be.

Comment: Welcome (back) to [vi.se]! Can you please [edit] to explain *it doesn't work*? (PS the only reason `java %` would work is the relatively new "java as scripts" thing where you don't have to compile single-file programs ahead-of-time. In more complicated projects that simply won't work.)

Answer (score 1):

To compile with `javac filename.java`, then use `javac %`. (+the backslash)

If you want to execute `java filename`  without the extension, then use `java %<` .

Note, there is exists a `:compiler javac` that also change the `'errorformat'` option, but it won't inject the current filename, you'd have to compile with `:make %`